# Array to string conversion in Laravel 4 when logging in with Cartalyst Sentry

Tags: php, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have a problem. When I try to log in to my app, I get following message:

> ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion

Backtrace:

> /(insignificant)/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php

```
$dbDataCol = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
$dbIdCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];

try {
    $sql = "SELECT $dbDataCol FROM $dbTable WHERE $dbIdCol = :id";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
```

My piece of code that I use to log in:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $rules = [
        'login'     =>  'required',
        'password'  =>  'required'
    ];
    
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        $remember = (bool) Input::get('rememberMe', false);
        
        try
        {
            $user = Sentry::authenticate([
                'login'     =>  Input::get('login'),
                'password'  =>  Input::get('password')
            ], $remember);
            
            Session::flash('successes', array_merge((array) Session::get('successes'), ['Witaj, ' . $user->displayname]));
            return Redirect::intended(URL::route('home'));
        }
        catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e)
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('login', 'Login lub hasło nieprawidłowe.');
            $validator->errors()->add('password', 'Login lub hasło nieprawidłowe.');
            
            return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('login', 'Login lub hasło nieprawidłowe.');
            $validator->errors()->add('password', 'Login lub hasło nieprawidłowe.');
            
            return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e)
        {
            Session::flash('dangers', ['Konto nieaktywne. Kliknij na link, który dostałeś mailem. Jeśli go nie dostałeś, skontaktuj się z administratorem.']);

            return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Throttling\UserBannedException $e)
        {
            Session::flash(['dangers', 'Konto zablokowane. Skontaktuj się z administratorem.']);
            
            return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using database driver for cookies, and error only occurs when Remember Me checked ($remember = true)

Comment: Switching back session to native solves it?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I had some space issues with 'native' driver (particularily not enough place for all my session data), so it's not a solution.

Comment: So if you're telling us that native works, but you just won't use it, it's might be because your `sessions` table structure might be different from what you need for your version of Laravel. Can you show us your migration for it?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Migration made afresh with artisan session:table and my previous migration are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by downgrading form 4.1 to 4. I think it's some kind of bug.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your authenticate call:

```
$user = Sentry::authenticate(array(
    'login'     =>  Input::get('login'),
    'password'  =>  Input::get('password')
), $remember);
```

Comment: That's the same thing as what he has, just without the short array syntax. Won't change anything...

Comment: @Cryode I also noticed it. I use PHP >5.5, so it's not an issue here.